# Ember route and link structure

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just starting to learn ember. Currently still trying to learn route and url. Need to know the better way to do this because in my template in the index.html there is repetition of code in each of the handlebar templates to manage the menu.

**apps.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('home', { path: '/' });
   this.resource('students');
   this.resource('about');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="home">
  <b>HOME</b>
  {{#link-to 'students'}}Students{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}}

  <h1>Welcome to my Ember Web App</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="students">
  {{#link-to 'home'}}HOME{{/link-to}}
  <b>Students</b>
  {{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}}

  <h1>Students List</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
  {{#link-to 'home'}}HOME{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'students'}}Students{{/link-to}}
  <b>About{</b>

  <h1>About this web app</h1>
</script>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the application template to have things like a header and a footer, etc. There is a good description in the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/the-application-template/).

So, you need a template which looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#link-to 'index'}} HOME {{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'students'}}Students{{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}}
    <div>
    {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
```

With this, your templates for the specific routes become significantly smaller because they get rendered to where you placed the `{{outlet}}` expression in the application template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="students"> 
  <h1>Students List</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: how do I update the application template so that the current route link that is active will not have active links and bold, like my original code and in that picture?

Comment: The active link is supposed to have `class="active"` attribute on it, so you can use CSS to style it accordingly, see http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/